automatic dependency generation for c++20 modules
I try to use c++ module. For any real world project is is needed to get the dependencies automatically.
If I use "old-style" include <bla>; include "blub" I simply can use g++ -M or g++ -MM.
If I use modules in my files, I have no idea how to get the deps for them.
Example project has two files:
export module f1module;
import <iostream>;


export void f1()
{
    std::cout << "Check" << std::endl;
}

and
import <iostream>;
import <sstream>;
import f1module;


int main()
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "Test"; 
    std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
    f1();
}

I tried:
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++26 -M   f1.cpp
<built-in>: warning: module dependencies require preprocessing
<built-in>: note: you should use the '-MD' option
f1.o: f1.cpp /usr/include/stdc-predef.h

$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++26 -M -MD  f1.cpp
<built-in>: warning: module dependencies require preprocessing
<built-in>: note: you should use the '-MD' option

$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++26 -MD -M  f1.cpp
<built-in>: warning: module dependencies require preprocessing
<built-in>: note: you should use the '-MD' option

$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++26 -MD  f1.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/14/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idea how to get any Makefile rules to generate the gcm files?

Related: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Preprocessing.html  MD flags require that, but docs are vague about how to use it?

Btw, these #include aren't "old style", they are mainstream. import modules are part of feature known as "compiled module interface". In a way it's similar to Pascal modules (funny enough in Pascal they are called "units"). They can be used compiked, so have a CMI file. It might be part of totally external project you don't have access to. So perhaps what we want wasn't meant to be a part of day-to-day routine which should be automated.

If you can get gcc to support import std;, you might no longer have to care about standard headers.
